# Natural number that has a remainder of $1, 2, 3, 4$ respectively after dividing...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

A number when divided by 2 leaves a remainder of 1. When it is divided by 3 leaves a remainder 2. When it is divided by 4 it leaves a remainder of 3. And when it is divided by 5 it leaves remainder of 4. What should be the number ?

Note : I already formulated some formula but I think it might not work:

**x = 2a + 1

x = 3b + 2

x = 4c + 3

x = 5d + 4**

Comment: $60n-1$ for any integer $n$ (and no others).

Comment: Note: Every number which satisfies that when divided by $4$ it leaves a remainder of $3$ must also satisfy the condition that when divided by $2$ it leaves remainder $1$, so the first condition in your question can be entirely ignored.  To solve your question this is a straightforward application of the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).

Comment: The information about the remainder after division by $2$ is redundant. Observe that $2\cdot 20=3\cdot 13+1$, $3\cdot 15=4\cdot 11+1$, and $8\cdot 12=5\cdot 15+1$. Therefore, $3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot n+2\cdot 20\cdot 2+3\cdot 15\cdot 3+8\cdot 12\cdot 4$ should leave those remainders. This construction is the interpolation technique used in the existencial part of the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Proof).

Comment: The super-simple way on this one, BTW: if $x$ divided by $3$ leaves a remainder of $2$, then $(x+1)$ is a multiple of $3$.  Likewise, $x+1$ is a multiple of $4$, and of $5$.  What can you say about it, then?

Comment: [Closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1832200/11619).

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem in number theory solved by the *Chinese remainder theorem*.  You can look up this algorithm many places, but indeed the (smallest) solution (as posted by @metamorphy) is $59$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ you get 'for free' that $x \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$. So these two conditions toghether are equivalent to the first one. Thus, you're looking at

$$
\cases{
x \equiv 3 \pmod{4} \\
x \equiv 2 \pmod{3} \\
x \equiv 4 \pmod{5}
}$$

By the [chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), this system of equations has a unique solution modulo $4\cdot3\cdot5 = 60$. The only numbers in $\{1,\dots,60\}$ that are congruent to $4$ modulo $5$ are

$$
0, 4,9,14,19,24,29,34,39,44,49,54,59.
$$

Now, our number is odd by the first observation, so we can reduce the former to check only these

$$
9,19,29,39,49,59
$$

and finally, only $59$ here is $2$ modulo $3$. Thus, the solutions have the form

$$
60k + 59
$$

or since $59 \equiv -1 \pmod{60}$,

$$
60k -1 \quad (k \in \mathbb{Z})
$$

Answer (score 0):

Continuing your thought:
$$\begin{cases}x=2a+1\\x=3b+2\\x=4c+3\\x=5d+4\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}x=2a+1\\2a+1=3b+2\\2a+1=4c+3\\2a+1=5d+4 \end{cases}\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}x=2a+1\\a=\frac12(3b+1)\\3b+2=4c+3\\3b+2=5d+4 \end{cases}\Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}x=2a+1\\a=\frac12(3b+1)\\b=\frac13(4c+1)\\
4c+3=5d+4 \end{cases}\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}x=2a+1\\a=\frac12(3b+1)\\b=\frac13(4c+1)\\
c=\frac14(5d+1) \end{cases}$$
Now you must solve the last Diophantine equation (or by trial and error) and find backwards:
$$d=11,c=14,b=19,d=29,x=59.$$
Alternatively, using modular arithmetic:
$$\begin{cases}
x\equiv 1\pmod{2}\\
x\equiv 2\pmod{3}\\
x\equiv 3\pmod{4}\\
x\equiv 4\pmod{5}\end{cases} \Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x=2a+1\\
2a+1=2\pmod{3}\\
2a+1=3\pmod{4}\\
2a+1=4\pmod{5} \end{cases}\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x=2a+1\\
a\equiv 2\pmod{3}\\
a\equiv 1\pmod{2}\\
a\equiv 4\pmod{5} \end{cases}\Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}
x=2a+1\\
a=3b+2\\
3b+2\equiv1\pmod{2}\\
3b+2\equiv 4\pmod{5} \end{cases}\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x=2a+1\\
a=3b+2\\
b\equiv-1\pmod{2}\\
b\equiv 4\pmod{5} \end{cases}\Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x=2a+1\\
a=3b+2\\
b=2c-1\\
2c-1\equiv 4\pmod{5} \end{cases}\Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}
x=2a+1\\
a=3b+2\\
b=2c-1\\
c\equiv 0\pmod{5} \end{cases} \Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
\color{red}{x}=2(30n-1)+1=\color{red}{60n-1}\\
a=3(10n-1)+2=30n-1\\
b=2(5n)-1=10n-1\\
c=5n, n\in \mathbb Z \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

If we increase $a,b,c,d$ by one from your system of equations, observe that these equations now tell us that $x=2a-1=3b-1=4c-1=5d-1$ with the new values. Thus $x+1=3b=4c=5d$, so $60|(x+1)$; thus $x=60n-1$ for any integer $n$.